# Why isn't IIS 7.5 accepting any request with URLs containing the word 'handler'?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, iis-7, iis-7.5

We've noticed 2 very weird IIS 7.5 problems running on Windows Server 2008 and ASP.NET 3.5

1. Any requests that contain the word 'handler' result in an HTTP 502.1 error (timeout)
2. Some requests, which we didn't yet identify a possible logic, result in an HTTP 411 error (The request must be chunked or have a content length)

Aditional information:

- The errors only occur when our server is accessed from the internet, outside our network. Everything is fine when the server is accessed internally.

Please help ups, because we found absolutely no help on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

502 is a Bad Gateway error. It *usually* indicates a failure of one web device to talk to another.

That might indicate that there's a reverse proxy or similar between the Internet and your web server, and they're having issues talking to each other.

Sometimes the error will indicate the type of device involved - Apache, ISA Server, or whatever.

The *handler* problem could indicate a security-related filter on the reverse proxy.

That'd explain why it's only from the Internet that there's a problem, as well.