# Is there a way to download and activate a predefined-configuration for IIS 7.5 that is less restrictive?

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-7.5

All I want is to set up a server that works. I'm not interested in security now.

As I asked [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/188148/why-isnt-iis-7-5-accepting-any-request-with-urls-containing-the-word-handler), I can't even make IIS 7.5 to handle URLs that contain the word 'handler'. I suspect that it's due to the security improviments of IIS 7.5, that, by default, comes activated.

I'm studing it but so far I got no result.

Can I download and activate a a predefined configuration for IIS that is less restrictive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word 'handler' isn't a reserved word that is blocked in IIS 7.5.  Can you get a simple test.htm page working?  I suspect that this is related to something else.

I haven't heard of anyone providing predefined configurations, but if you do a basic install of IIS and review the items to install then you should be able to get a machine that works well.  If you're just testing, you can turn on virtually everything during the install to ensure that you're not missing an important component.